# How to Serve Angular SSR with Existing Node Js?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am working on a website which uses Node JS for the backend and Angular with SSR for the frontend. Thus far, I have been running the two applications separately, but I am now looking for ways to serve everything directly from the backend repository, as this would simplify things. I think this can be achieved by a combination of somehow exporting my entire Angular application into a module which I can then npm install into the backend project, then import some Angular modules to serve Angular + static files, and keep the /api endpoints as they exist now.

However, I have not been able to find any literature which outlines this process, which leads me to believe this is not a typical use case and might not even be possible. Can anyone recommend any reading or best practices regarding this, or alternatives?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Have the same question

Comment: I eventually decided to just use two separate server instances, one for the frontend and one for the backend. The Angular ssr server routes API calls to the backend, which will only accept the calls when routed from ssr.

Comment: Thank you. Was also hoping it can just be done from one server.